# How can i send data from the client to an Server and then back to the client

Tags: c#

I recently talked to a friend. He told me that he uses in his company as backend C-Sharp. There he exchanges data with a client via a website. Now I would like to know how it works. I know how i can do GET and POST Request to a website but i would like to do something like:

When you upload a folder, this data is sent to the backend. They are converted into something else and when it's done, you get a DL link

Best Regards
Mathias

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I did not think it was really just that

Comment: I did not try so much. Just simple GET and POST requests. It was primarily about the interaction between C-Sharp and JavaScript, PHP etc

Comment: But if it really is not much then I think I will not have a problem with it. Thought there is a lot more behind it